# Diagnosing ADL crash?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

**Project:** AIR desktop, Flex 4.6, AIR 15, OSX 10.9.5, Flash Builder 4.6

I am getting an ADL crash which I haven't been able to diagnose. I've littered my code with trace statements, try/catch statements and breakpoints without tracking down the issue. Memory usage doesn't seem excessive. What is odd is that it *doesn't* crash when I profile the app.

The only thing I can think of is this is some kind of race condition which running in "profile" mode masks. That or garbage collection which is somehow delayed in "profile" mode. The OSX crash log cites `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`but nothing else that I can understand in terms of my code.

Has anyone encountered this sort of ADL crash or recognize these symptoms?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

**Project: AIR desktop, AIR 17, OSX 10.10.3**

Yes, same thing here... but I'm getting SIGSEGV:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
```

... which turns out to be an "invalid memory access" message. The last human-readable crash line reads shows:

```
... __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
```

Then the rest is just hex values on the com.adobe.AIR. I've also littered with trace, and debug-step-throughs, yada yada.

When I incorporate a delay in code execution (via setTimout), the crashes don't seem to happen. So I think it might be some kind of race condition across asynchronous load/complete.

I don't believe it has anything to do with garbage collection / memory -- as far as I've been able to monitor.

I'm bummed.

Comment: I feel your pain. . .  ;-)  It does seem to be some sort of loading thing– I am loading a .psd file andI have a Spark List which displays layer thumbnails and names. My next step is going to be just to disable all of that – start whittling away more code until the crash stops. Fun. . . Good luck with your `SIGSEGV`!

Comment: I think I solved my problem. Seems that it involved the component lifecycle and *maybe* data binding. The scenario: I open a Panel subClass through the PopUpManager and have the Panel load image assets. A TileList displays thumbnails of the images. The loading *may* have been occurring before the Panel was fully initialized. Moved the loading code to the creationComplete event and the crash *seems* resolved. This would correlate with the race condition/doesn't happen with delays, etc. Don't know if that is the source of your crash but thought I'd offer it as a possibility.

Comment: Tomato -- my situation doesn't have any view construction occurring. I am using Starling + feathers and thought that there might have been some code in there that was causing the problem... I even went so far as to remove all the starling and feathers UI components (yes, I rebuilt new UI components from scratch) and just went with vanilla AS3... While the crashes were not as profound, they still did occur -- so it's not a starling nor feathers issue.